# SimpleXML - Group By Element Attribute value

Tags: php, xml, attributes, simplexml, grouping

well am stuck again
I am trying to group xml data based on the attribute 'name' value

XML Feed Return Data

```
 <Sport sport_code="FOOT" name="Football" disporder="-1000">
<SBClass sb_class_id="12430" disporder="-999" name="France">
<SBType sb_type_id="26463" name="France - Coupe de France" disporder="52">
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="Gazélec Fco Ajaccio v Sainte Marienne" start_time="2016-01-02T12:30:00" virtual="N" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="Y" mkt_count="37" ev_id="3400770" disporder="-9996">
<EvDetail br_match_id="8548770"/>
<Inplay inplay_period_num="1" clock_status="TICKING" correct_at="2016-01-02T12:50:11" inplay_period="first_half" score_string="0-0" last_change="2016-01-01T09:45:07" inplay_secs="1209"/>
<Teams>
<Team team_id="3411" team_order="0" name="Gazélec Fco Ajaccio" short_name="Gazélec Fco Ajaccio"/>
<Team team_id="172231" team_order="1" name="Sainte Marienne" short_name="Sainte Marienne"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
</SBType>
</SBClass>

<SBClass sb_class_id="12430" disporder="-999" name="UK">
<SBType sb_type_id="26463" name="France - Coupe de France" disporder="52">
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="Gazélec Fco Ajaccio v Sainte Marienne" start_time="2016-01-02T12:30:00" virtual="N" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="Y" mkt_count="37" ev_id="3400770" disporder="-9996">
<EvDetail br_match_id="8548770"/>
<Inplay inplay_period_num="1" clock_status="TICKING" correct_at="2016-01-02T12:50:11" inplay_period="first_half" score_string="0-0" last_change="2016-01-01T09:45:07" inplay_secs="1209"/>
<Teams>
<Team team_id="3411" team_order="0" name="Gazélec Fco Ajaccio" short_name="Gazélec Fco Ajaccio"/>
<Team team_id="172231" team_order="1" name="Sainte Marienne" short_name="Sainte Marienne"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
</SBType>
</SBClass>
</Sport>
```

I want it to group ALL data based on SBClass attribute 'name' value
e.g. France, UK ( this value is dynamic btw so cant add fixed string values )

Am really struggling with this. have tried other examples but they only work if the data to group by is inside the node eg `<node>DATA</node>`

Hope someone can help with this

** Edit **

I have tried most of the grouping suggestions that are here on S.O.

```
    $xmlData = 'http://feeds-sports.winner.com/odds_feed?key=get_events_for_sport&sport_code=FOOT&on_date=2016-01-02';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);

$leagues = $xml->xpath('/Sport/SBClass[@name="United Kingdom"]');
var_dump($leagues);    // var_dump #1
```

Its not even dumping anything at all

I want it to display the data like this 
Category : France ( or relevant value from SBClass attribute 'name' )
SBType name value : e.g France - Coupe de France
Ev name value : e.g Gazélec Fco Ajaccio v Sainte Marienne

Then display all data for "France"

Then all data for Category : UK 
etc

** 2ND EDIT **
Here is the XML feed showing ALL data
http://feeds-sports.winner.com/odds_feed?key=get_match_markets_for_sport&lang=en&sb_class_id=12430&sport_code=FOOT&mkt_sort=MRES

I want to group it by the value of SBType->attributes()->{'name'}

Comment: Can you share an example that you have tried? Can you give an example of the expected grouped data structure?

Comment: your code seems correct: https://eval.in/496340. No result because in your `xpath`-expression, you select "United Kingdom" as in your XML the `name` attribute is "UK".

Comment: no i copied xml feed & shortened the data I typed that UK in the xml code above in error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is loop the `$xml->Sport->SBClass` nodes and check if the name attribute exists.

If the name attribute exists, you can add the item to an array (for example `$sbClassGroups`) and use the name attribute to create the array key for the group (France, Spain etc..)

Now that you have the grouped data, you can loop this `$sbClassGroups` array using for example a `foreach` construct to get the values from the elements which are of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

```
$xmlData = 'http://feeds-sports.winner.com/odds_feed?key=get_events_for_sport&sport_code=FOOT&on_date=2016-01-02';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);

$sbClassGroups = array();

foreach ($xml->Sport->SBClass as $item) {
    if (isset($item->attributes()->name)) {
        $sbClassGroups[(string)$item->attributes()->name][] = $item;
    }
}

foreach ($sbClassGroups as $sbClassGroup) {
    foreach( $sbClassGroup as $sbClass) {
        echo "<br><b>" . $sbClass->attributes()->name . "</b><br>";

        foreach ($sbClass->SBType as $sbt) {
            echo "<br>" . $sbt->attributes()->name . "<br>";

            foreach ($sbt->Ev as $ev) {
                echo "<i>" . $ev->attributes()->name . "</i><br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant thanks displaying perfectly

1 more question if you don't mind
How can I display each group & entries under each in a <select> list

Comment: You can use the values in the foreach loops to dynamically create and populate the [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) elements.

Comment: Maybe a setup like this is what you mean? `foreach ($sbClassGroups as $sbClassGroup) {
    foreach( $sbClassGroup as $sbClass) {
        echo "<br><b>" . $sbClass->attributes()->name . "</b><br>";

        foreach ($sbClass->SBType as $sbt) {
            echo sprintf('<br>%1$s<br><select name="%1$s">', (string)$sbt->attributes()->name);

            foreach ($sbt->Ev as $ev) {
                echo sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', (string)$ev->attributes()->name);
            }

            echo "</select><br><br>";
        }
    }
}`

Comment: brilliant !!
is there a way i can limit the number of results returned for
foreach ($sbt->Ev as $ev) {